# Handle events in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the SAP GUI Scripting API reference at VBA, I would like to know if there is some way to do things when an event happens. I am really new to VBA.

Class and event

[image]

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/10307820/how-to-make-excel-vba-monitor-sap-gui-events.html

Comment: The question is not specific to SAP GUI Scripting. The question is about how to catch [events in VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/).